# Getting blank line when moving background image (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing the game using andengine.. i moving the background image using AutoParallaxBackground..Its working fine.. But i got a blank line between the images..No problem with images

```
ie: autoParallaxBackground.addParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-20.0f, new Sprite(0, 0, this.bgTextureRegion1)));
```

How to fix this issue ?

[image]

Device screen shot... Blank line visible at left corner

image size : 720x480
camera size: 720x480
mobile screen size: 320x240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the black background of the TextureAtlas bleeding over to the image when bilinear filtering is applied. The solution is to double the leftmost and rightmost 1px line, so that the bleedover has the right color. Here's a nasty fix that should prove that this really is the problem, it however triples the time needed to load the background so it is not useful for production code. When you create the TextureAtlas for the background, do it similarly to this:

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.backgroundBitmapTexture, this, "background.png", 0, 0);
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.backgroundBitmapTexture, this, "background.png", 2, 0);
this.backgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.backgroundBitmapTexture, this, "background.png", 1, 0);
```

What this does is to load the texture three times, the first two times shifted by one px left and right. The third call creates the actual texture region between the two.

Comment: yes. now problem fixed..Its working fine. But same think repeating 3 times..it will  take more loading time ? ... I using 4 bg images in game

Comment: Yes, doing that will increase loading time, it's just a test to see whether you have the problem I was talking about. A more correct way is to extract the 1px line from the background as a separate image and load that small picture instead. Even better would be to access the texture and do it via OpenGL, but my kung-fu is not strong enough to do that :-) Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes.. extract answer.. but how and where to place 1px line from background image..

Answer (score 0):

The Bilinear Texture Option was exactly the problem. In GLES2.0, you can either eliminate the TextureOptions.BILINEAR or you can change it to NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA.

Answer (score 0):

**implement preDraw() method for your background sprite and set  pGLState.enableDither();**

```
new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HIGHT,
                    this.mParallaxLayerBack, vertexBufferObjectManager) {

                @Override
                protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {

                    super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                    pGLState.enableDither();
                }

            }
```